# Quiero agregar un boton que elimine el bloque con la informacion de la vista y la informacion de la base de datos

Tags: python, flask, mysqldb

```
{% for i in data %}
<div class="resultado" id="resultado">
    <p>Key: {{i[0]}}, Username: {{i[1]}}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Cada vez que recibe los datos agrega una columna con esos datos pero la verdad no se como poner la opcion de tener un boton de eliminar esa columna y los datos de la base de datos.

se me ocurre con el id pero no se como implementarlo, ayudenme porfavor.

(estoy usando flask para mysql)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual de todas las cosas que tenes que hacer, no sabes implementar???

Comment: Es simple, debes usar ajax para enviarle al servidor que tiene eliminar esos datos de ti base de dato usar form para enviarle la petición http de eliminarlo. Si quieres eliminar la fila al nivel cliente (JavaScript), no debes usar id para identificar varios elementos que tendran el mismo id(el id esta hecho para ser una identificación unica), debes usar el atributo class que esta diseñado para eso y lo obtienes con document.getElementsByClassName("tu-clase");, que retorna una lista de todos los elementos con la misma clase

Comment: (Ojo: Si le envias la petición http debes tratarla con flask y eliminarlo desde el servidor)